# How to get and create custom variables from a text file in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

So, I'm making a program (hopefully) that is an 'improved' command prompt.
In my program, I want it to get all lines from a text file.
The text file will contain lines that look like this:

```
desktop=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
scripts=D:\Scripts
```

What I want my program to do, is to read through that, and create new variables such as:

```
desktop = "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop"
scripts = "D:\Scripts"
```

I know there are probably better and safer ways to do this, but for now, I'd like to do it this way. Here is my code so far (it doesn't work):

```
with open("custom_shortcuts.txt","r") as f:
    customShortcuts = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]
for i in customShortcuts:
    parts = i.split("=")
    varName = str(parts[0])
    varValue = str(parts[1])
    eval("varName = varValue")
```

As you can see, I tried to use eval(), and failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you work with dictionaries instead?

```
text = r'''desktop=C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
scripts=D:\Scripts'''

var = dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in text.splitlines())
print(var)
{'desktop': 'C:\\Users\\%username%\\Desktop', 'scripts': 'D:\\Scripts'}
```

It isn't good practice to dynamically inject variables into your namespace. If you want the value for `desktop`, you'd access it as `var['desktop']`.

Comment: This seems like a better idea, thanks. I'll try it out!